# How do Path of War stances work out of combat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, path-of-war

In Dreamscarred Press's [Path of War](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war) (a 3rd Party supplement to Pathfinder), it's unclear to me what can('t) be done out of combat, especially with regard to stances.

Lines like this (from [System & Use](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/systems-and-use)) imply one might be in a stance all day long:

> A stance remains in effect indefinitely and is never expended. The benefit of your chosen stance continues until you change to another stance you know as a swift action.

Though this implies there could be some limit, or at least that they're intended for combat more than out of combat:

> A stance is a type of fighting method that you maintain from round to round. So long as you stay in a stance, you gain some benefit from it. A martial disciple who performs a kata and assumes a specific posture as he prepares to fight is using a stance.

Lets take as an example this stance from the Shattered Mirror discipline (which was just released in the Harbinger PDF but isn't yet on the PFSRD).

> *Silvered Mirror Stance (Su):* When you assume this stance, choose a single non-personal range power, psi-like ability, spell, or spell-like ability affecting you. While you maintain this stance, allies within 30 feet of you also gain the benefits of the chosen effect for as long as it is affecting you

This would be an amazing way to share buffs out of combat, e.g. casting Overland Flight or Stoneskin on the Harbinger and getting it for free on any ally within 30'. What are the limits to this?

Comment: Notably, the chief limit on Silvered Mirror is that eventually the buff itself will run dry.

Comment: The phrasing "that you maintain from round to round" smells like combat-only, but it's definitely not explicit. Good find!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A stance can usually be initiated as a swift action, and its effect usually lasts until it would end ("stance" duration).

• A stance ends if you enter another stance.
• A stance ends if you become helpless.
• A stance ends if you spend a swift action to end it.

There is no limit on stances aside from these and stance-specific effects. Yes, you can use a 9th-level harbinger to share useful spells out of combat. Yes, you can begin the day by entering a damage-aura stance and have it stay up on you until you go to bed. The possibilities are endless!